# Rails ActiveConcern call Private Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the following block of (simplified) Rails Code. Is there any way to call `my_internal_method` from the class_methods section? I'm still pretty new to Ruby/Rails, and I read the documentation for `ActiveSupport::Concern`, but it didn't make the most sense.

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def bar
      my_internal_method
    end
  end

  def foo
    my_internal_method
  end

  private

  def my_internal_method
  end
end
```

Or alternatively, is there any way of calling `bar` in `foo`? which was the real reason I went down this path to begin with.

Thoughts?

Comment: `new.send(:my_internal_method)` is the most natural way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a class method from an instance method

```
def foo
  self.class.bar
  my_internal_method
end
```

To call an instance method from a class method, you need to instantiate an instance object

```
def bar
  new.send(:my_internal_method)
end
```

Note that we had to use `send` as `my_internal_method` is private and so isn't accessible with an explicit receiver (i.e. you can't do `new.my_internal_method`)